# How do i customize my root reference?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am fairly new to Firebase and i have just finished adding Firebase authentication to my app. Now, i want to move to the next step which is to save a users account information on the database. I am confused where it come to creating my root reference. Say for example, i want my app's root Reference to be:

```
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("<My-URL>/android/apps/")
```

How do i add the sub-directories /android/apps/ to my database so that it shows on the firebase console?

The database page on the firebase console is still very confusing to me, please below is a screen shot of my console. I have marked two places in red. Please can somebody tell me the uses of these places.

[Screen shot of firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KxpS.png)

Comment: Please us the latest Firebase SDK, found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/. Using the legacy SDK (as you are doing now) is just going to lead to a harder time than needed.

Comment: ok thanks puf, i will do as u have said